# How to read button mashing in c#

Tags: c#, console-application

I've been trying to get a button mashing minigame working in my RPG, but I haven't managed to get it to work. This is the code I've created:

```
using System;

namespace CounterAttack
{
class Program
{
    public static int n = 0;
    public static int buttonmash = 0;
    public static string buttonpressed;
    public static void CounterAttack()
    {
        n = 0;
        while (n < 4000)
        {
            buttonpressed = Console.ReadKey().ToString();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
            n = n + 1;
            if (buttonpressed == " ")
            {
                buttonmash = buttonmash + 1;
                buttonpressed = "a";
            }
            else
            {
                buttonpressed = "a";
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"You pressed spacebar {buttonmash} times ");
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CounterAttack();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.ReadKey(); 
    }
}
```

}

For reasons unknown to me, the program will not exit the while loop. This means I can't check if the other parts of code will work at all.

So my question is: How can I alter this code to read the amount of times spacebar has been pressed in 4 seconds?

Comment: `buttonpressed = Console.ReadKey().ToString();` will block the countdown `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);` will block the spacebar being pressed (also it's in milliseconds not seconds should be `Thread.Sleep(1000)` , to exit the loop you'll need to press the space bar and wait 1 second 4000 times.

Comment: You'll need to press a key 4000 times before you exit that loop.  You probably want to look at `Console.KeyAvailable` and only do a `Console.ReadKey` if there's a key to read.

Comment: Try doing this in a windows application, and counting KeyDown (or KeyUp) events. The console just waits for a key press

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sort-of works, so long as you press the space bar after the 4 second timer is up.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var startTime = DateTime.Now;
        var n = 0;
        while (DateTime.Now < startTime.AddSeconds(4))
        {
            var key = Console.ReadKey();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
            if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Spacebar) n = n + 1;
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"You pressed spacebar {n} times ");
    }
```

Comment: Awesome! this worked. Now I can implement this into my program. Thank you.

Comment: This doesn't work (You can hold down the spacebar to get the max score)

Answer (score 1):

"I've been trying to get a button mashing minigame working in my RPG, but I haven't managed to get it to work."

You are doing this in a console application. So the answer is on a spectrum from "not easily" to "plain impossible". I hope somebody else can give you answer with more precision along that axis.

Game development and the GUI technologies do not mix that well to begin with. That old Solitaire game was pretty much the upper limit of what games you can do in them. Console matches it even *less* then that.

All the serious game development is done in any enviroment that comes with a game loop. XNA is a bit dated, but for .NET Core there is some options: https://www.microsoft.com/net/apps/gaming

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
class Program
    {
        private static int numSpaces = 0;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Thread th = new Thread(CheckSpace);

            th.Start();
            th.Join();

            Console.WriteLine($"You pressed space {numSpaces} times");
            Console.Read();
        }

        private static void CheckSpace()
        {
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();

            while (true)
            {
                if (Console.KeyAvailable)
                {
                    if (Console.ReadKey().Key == ConsoleKey.Spacebar)
                    {
                        numSpaces++;
                    }
                }
                if (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds>= 4000)
                {

                    break;
                }

                Thread.Sleep(10);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

@auberg's solution is good, but you really don't need a second thread.  Yeah, calling `Thread.Sleep()` on the main thread is a bad idea, but doing it for such a short time is un-noticeable anyway.

Try this:

```
 public static void CountKeyPresses()
 {
     Console.WriteLine("OK, start pressing the space bar");
     var numPresses = 0;
     var stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
     stopWatch.Start();
     while (stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds < 4000)
     {
         if (Console.KeyAvailable && Console.ReadKey().Key == ConsoleKey.Spacebar)
         {
             ++numPresses;
         }
         System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
     }
     Console.WriteLine($"\r\nYou pressed the spacebar {numPresses} times");
 }
```